# Unable to connect to HDMI on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am unable to connect my laptop with external monitor while running Ubuntu 18.04. It works fine with Windows.

Here is the output of the command `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.02 +  60.00    60.01    59.98    48.01    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93* 
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.01  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

It shows HDMI-1 disconnected even when it is plugged in.
I have also tried running the following commands

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1920x1080
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP-1
```

but it outputs (after running the second command)

> xrandr: cannot find mode 1920x1080

Please suggest a work around for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. I had installed Ubuntu 18.04 and so my laptop would often not wake-up or result in a blank screen after suspending it. Other users also reported a similar issue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep). In order to resolve the suspend issue, I had set 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"` in the /etc/default/grub file.

However, setting this kernel parameter was causing a problem to detect external HDMI screen. After removing it and setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`, the Ubuntu seemed to detect and work fine with the external HDMI.